# Python performance

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numba

I have a question regarding the performance of my python program. The part which is written down is very essential and I already increased the performance with numpy. I would like to know if it is possible to make this part even faster? A 10x speed up would already be nice..

```
u = numpy.zeros((a**l, a**l))
re = numpy.zeros((a**l, a**l, a**l))
wp = numpy.zeros((a**l, 2))
...Some code which edits u,re and wp...
for x in range(N):
    wavg = numpy.dot(wp[:, 0], wp[:, 1])
    wp[:, 0] = 1.0/wavg*numpy.dot(u, numpy.multiply(wp[:, 0], wp[:, 1]))
    wp[:, 0] = numpy.tensordot(numpy.tensordot(re, wp[:, 0], axes=1), wp[:, 0], 
    axes=1)
```

Comment: Can you tell us anything about this code? Where are you running it, what does it do, what kind of input data do you have...

Comment: I would suggest [codereview.se]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se]. Questions on optimizing already-working code are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: u is the mutation matrix. re is a recombination tensor. wp[:,0] is the current population vector and wp[:,1] the fitness vector. a is always 2 and l is usually 8.

Comment: Have you tried Cython?

Comment: @linusg I think he wants to use numba for optimization. At least he added the numba-tag. But without using mathematical tricks this will be hard to optimize.

Comment: I think so too but I thought I would give it a try..

Comment: @linusg: I haven't tried that yet

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/128020/9357) on Code Review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a great experience with `Cython` (Another thing than `CPython`...). You can make plain `C` code out of your program, compile it to an extension and just run it from another Python file. See this question from me for more information on building an extension including `numpy`: [How to create a .pyd file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921961/python-how-to-create-a-pyd-file).

Sample:

Assuming you have your code compiled to an extension (`.pyd` on Windows, `.so` on every other platform), e.g. `myext.pyd` and a function `myfunc()` in it, you can run it like this:

```
import myext
myext.myfunc()
```

The Python Interpreter will run this little code snippet, load the extension (which is bytecode made from `C`-code, will be fast!) and run any function much faster than normal Python code.

You will need to install a compiler on Windows, `gcc` is already included in most Linux/Unix systems. There's a special Compiler package for Python 2.7, but this dies not work for Python 3.x. You can use `MinGW` on Windows, a Port of the `gcc` which works fine for me.

Sometimes `Cython` will generate 15k lines C code from about 300 lines Python Code, don't wonder about that :)

Feel free to ask if you have some more questions or need a more detailed description how to do that. Building a *working* Python extension is not that trivial...

Hope this helps!

Comment: I made some edits, may be useful information