# How to create a pyd file using command line

Tags: python-3.x

I'm just wondering how can i create a .pyd file using python3.5 on win10.By the way I just want to know how to create it using command line like how you create .pyc file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a .pyd file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921961/how-to-create-a-pyd-file)

Answer (score -2):

Something like

```
f = open("NAMEOFFILE.pyd", "r")
f.close()
```

should do the trick. this should work with other arbitrary file types. .txt, .json, .py, .whateverfileextensionyouwant

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: While `pyd` could technically be any type of content, you don't answer in any relevant way. Besides, the question was to **create** a pyd. Your answer only opens the file. So wrong in two ways.