# Unable to get a pyd file after cythonization Cython Python

Tags: python, windows, installation, cython, cythonize

Hi trying to implement cython however I do not get a helloworld.pyd file in my directory when I build the cython file. I am running on Windows 10.19043, python version 3.7.9 , cython version 0.29.28 . How would I be able to fix this issue and get the .pyd file on windows 10.

Contents of helloworld.pyx

```
print("Hello World")
```

Contents of setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("helloworld.pyx")
)
```

Used command on cmd to build the Cython file

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Directory:

[Image of the directory build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMwUe.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a .pyd file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921961/how-to-create-a-pyd-file)

Comment: Does running setup.py create any output? It probably does and that output probably true you exactly what the issue is.

Comment: It should create a helloworld.pyd file but it only creates a helloworld.c file